# What does a 7 - 6 mean in figured bass?

Tags: chords, harmony, figured-bass

[image]

Here in this voice leading exercise I am doing I have 73 going to 63 in the figured bass but I am not sure what this means for the voice leading.  I understand the 7-6 means that the 7th above the bass becomes a 6th above the bass but how would the 73 chord be spelt in the first place? I have doubled the C in my solution to the exercise but perhaps I should have had a 5th or kept the 6th coming from the previous chord?

Also, on a separate note, After a ii6 chord would going to a IV7 not be going backwards? From my understanding, IV usually comes before ii6 not after...

Comment: There's no suspension in your realization of the exercise, just an upper neighbor motion in the soprano voice.

Comment: Sorry, I rewrote the question.. hope its clearer

Comment: @Aaron that's because the figures specify an upper neighbor motion rather than a suspension.

Comment: @phoog The question was edited after my comment. Originally the question specifically referenced a 7-6 suspension.

Comment: @Aaron my point is that the absence of a 7-6 suspension is not a feature of this realization of the exercise; it is a feature of the exercise itself.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, I'm not sure where you're coming from on this. The original post said "I have a 63 chord coming from a 7-6 suspension"; I was just pointing out that OP did not, in fact, have a suspension. I wasn't commenting on the exercise; I was commenting on an error in the post, which was since fixed.

Comment: @Aaron I understand that.  My point is that it isn't possible to realize the given figures with a suspension.  In other words, your comment says (or seems to) that armani claimed incorrectly to have introduced a suspension in the realization.  I am saying that armani didn't make such a claim.  To say simply that it is wrong to identify the 7-6 figure as a suspension, it would have been better to omit the words "your realization of."  Yet another way of saying it: I read your comment as saying "you mischaracterized what you wrote" rather than "you mischaracterized the given figured bass."

Comment: @phoog okay, now I see where you were coming from. But why don’t the figures admit a suspension? A 6 chord suspended over a stepwise descending bass then resolving to another 6 chord seems quite standard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133580/discussion-between-phoog-and-aaron).

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that, in this style, IV comes before ii and not after.

These 7–6 figures are tricky, because it *looks* like the figures are telling you to write a seventh chord (hence IV7) on the downbeat. But in actuality, that 7 is a non-chord tone, and the true figure is only 6 (hence a first-inversion chord, or ii6).

Think of it much like the cadential six-four: the 6/4 don't really tell you what the chord is, but rather they're accented non-chord tones that delay the true figures of 5 and 3. The same is true here: the 7, a non-chord tone, delays the 6, the actual chord tone.

As such, both beats 3 *and* 4 are ii6 chords, it's just that we have an accented non-chord tone B on beat 4. What you have in your image is correct, especially since you're not doubling the A in another voice (which would destroy the impact of the B non-chord tone). Note, though, that you're doubling the *bass* in your solution, not the *root*.